# How to publish data in Spring webflux hierarchy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm developing a proxy application with spring webflux. The client sends a request to fetch first 100 records. The server 1(Spring webflux project) sends a request to server 2, and fetch first 100 records(`Flux<MyData>`) and then applies a filter on it(reject some data), Now server 1 has less than 100 records, So It has to send another request to fetch exactly 100 correct records. But I can't do it dynamically with Spring webflux. How can I collect 100 records dynamically?

**Note:** I have `fetchData` method that send request via WebClient erto get `max` records from `first` record.

```
Flux<MyData> fetchData(int first, int max){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Use the expand() operator to trigger a new search (or not) recursively, until you've reached the desired number of elements.

Comment: @JBNizet Notice the fetchData function